# Checking if a file exisits in javascript and HTML, if you open the page locally

Tags: javascript, html, file, google-chrome

How do I read/check if a file in the same folder of the page exists, when I open the html page locally. The page is made for local use only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Local Files with Local Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903959/access-local-files-with-local-javascript)

Comment: use node.js with `fs` (file system) and existsSync or stat https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

Answer (score -3):

try making an ajax request to retrieve the file. Example with jQuery:

```
$.get('url to your local file')
.done(()=>{ alert('file exists'); })
.fail(()=>{alert('file cannot be retrieved');});
```

Comment: I get the popup "file cannot be retrieved"

Comment: if the file actually exists, make sure the url is correct and you run your script and access the file from the same domain. e.g. http://localhost/

Comment: As said, the file is opened locally, so there is no domain. It is offline.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

You may need to install a local server for such functionality